# Remoting powershell across a VPN

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I've seen a few different tutes covering remoting configuration - [this one](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_remote.htm) seems better than average - but I'm not clear how I configure for a situation where the workstations are not of the same domain.

I'm using LogMeIn/Hamachi to create a VPN - I'd like an overview of the steps required to allow script execution for these workstations. Specifically, how do I define TrustedHosts so that onle my VPN peers are permitted?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the LogMeIn\Hamachi VPN network, but I assume that the hostnames are preserved when using it. (it not this may not help!)

If you want to trust a particular machine you use this:

```
set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value <Remote-computer-name>
```

If it's a domain you can use this:

```
set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value *.subdomain.domain.com
```

Check out the about FAQ as well (`Get-Help about_Remote_FAQ`) - that's where the first came from, the second I've used.

HTH,
Matt